# Pecl Memcache and php5-memcache

Tags: php, memcached, pecl

As I've read on different sources, pecl memcache and php5-memcache is an extension (correct me if I am wrong). If both of them are the same extension, is it okay to install them both?

This is the tutorial that do: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-12-04

Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

I can guarantee you that the tutorial is not installing memcache extension twice.

The command below installs the php-memcache extension along with php5 and mysql extension

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql php5 php5-memcache`

Then `sudo apt-get install memcached` installs the memcache daemon.

Comment: i am asking also about pecl. so what can you say about it?

Comment: you can use pecl to build the extension locally.

Comment: I want to return to my previous config before I install pecl. My memcache version now is 2.2.7. Before it was 3.0.6. So how can I restore to 3.0.6?

Comment: The latest memcache version is `v1.4.15`, so i assume your talking about the version of the memcache extension for php. So do `pecl uninstall memcache` and `sudo apt-get install php-memcache`